# How to select a styles within a font family for a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I've used

```
font_add_google(name = "Outfit", family = "Outfit")
```

to install the Outfit font family at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Outfit.

Using, e.g.

```
element_text(family = "Outfit")
```

I can successfully apply the regular Outfit font to my ggplot objects. That all works fine. How can I access the substyles of this font, e.g. Thin, ExtraLight, Light, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "different" fonts differ only in the weight, i.e. Regular has a weight of 400, whereas ExtraLight has a weight of 200. By default `font_add_google` downloads the (regular) font with weight 400 and one with a weight of 700 used with `fontface="bold"`. However, both weights could be set via the `regular.wt` and the `bold.wt` argument.

This said, if you want to use multiple variants or styles of the same font you have to download them separately with their respective weights and of course assign a different label to each via the `family` argument.

```r
library(showtext)
#> Loading required package: sysfonts
#> Loading required package: showtextdb
library(ggplot2)

wt <- seq(100, 900, 100)

purrr::walk(
  wt,
  \(x) font_add_google(
    name = "Outfit",
    family = paste0("Outfit", x),
    regular.wt = x
  )
)

showtext_auto()

dat <- data.frame(
  wt = wt,
  name = paste0("Outfit", wt)
)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_text(aes(label = name, x = 0, y = wt, family = name),
    size = 10
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. I learned how to do the thing and also learned how fonts actually work.